# Handling the token expiration in fastapi

Tags: python, security, scope, token, fastapi

I'm new with fastapi security and I'm trying to implement the authentication thing and then use scopes.

The problem is that I'm setting an expiration time for the token but after the expiration time the user still authenticated and can access services

```
import json
from jose import jwt,JWTError
from typing import Optional
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from fastapi.security import  OAuth2PasswordBearer,OAuth2PasswordRequestForm,SecurityScopes
from fastapi import APIRouter, UploadFile, File, Depends, HTTPException,status
from tinydb import TinyDB,where
from tinydb import Query
from passlib.hash import bcrypt
from pydantic import BaseModel
from passlib.context import CryptContext
##

class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Optional[str] = None
class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str

router = APIRouter()
SECRET_KEY="e79b2a1eaa2b801bc81c49127ca4607749cc2629f73518194f528fc5c8491713"
ALGORITHM="HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=1
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/dev-service/api/v1/openvpn/token")
db=TinyDB('app/Users.json')
Users = db.table('User')
User = Query

pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password:str

def get_user(username: str):#still
    user= Users.search((where('name') ==name))
    if user:
        return user[0]



@router.post('/verif')
async def verify_user(name,password):
    user = Users.search((where('name') ==name))
    print(user)
    if not user:
        return False
    print(user)
    passw=user[0]['password']
    if not bcrypt.verify(password,passw):
        return False
    return user


def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: Optional[timedelta] = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=1)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt

@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def token_generate(form_data:OAuth2PasswordRequestForm=Depends()):
    user=await verify_user(form_data.username,form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": form_data.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires)
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

@router.get('/user/me')
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user =Users.search(where('name') ==token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user

@router.post('/user')
async def create_user(name,password):
    Users.insert({'name':name,'password':bcrypt.hash(password)})
    return True
```

How can I really see the expiration of the token and how can I add the scopes?

Comment: You're not validating the expiry time of the token in `get_current_user` (which should be a function you use in `Depends`, not a view by itself); you'll have to actually check the expiry time for it to be useful. Where do you expect the expiry time to be checked otherwise? It also doesn't seem like you're checking if the user has a valid token in most of your view endpoints?

Comment: I still don't get how to validate the token and test its expiration date,maybe I'm still not understanding the concept very well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had pretty much the same confusion when I started out with FastAPI. The access token you created will not expire on its own, so you will need to check if it is expired while validating the token at `get_current_user`. You could modify your `TokenData` schema to the code below:

```
class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Optional[str] = None
    expires: Optional[datetime]
```

And your `get_current_user` to:

```
@router.get('/user/me')
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    # get the current user from auth token

    # define credential exception
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )

    try:
        # decode token and extract username and expires data
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        expires = payload.get("exp")
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception

    # validate username
    if username is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    token_data = TokenData(username=username, expires=expires)
    user = Users.search(where('name') == token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception

    # check token expiration
    if expires is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    if datetime.utcnow() > token_data.expires:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

Scopes is a huge topic on its own, so I can't cover it here. However, you can read more on it at the fastAPI docs [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/)

Comment: It is good to know that. You can mark the answer as accepted for the benefit of others who will have a similar problem.

Comment: This doesn't work, `jwt.decode` raises an `ExpiredSignatureError` if the token is expired, which is a `JWTError`. This means that the "check expiration code" you wrote will never be reached.

Answer (score 10):

I 'd wanted to comment on Unyime Etim's advice
but have no rating yet so this would be a separate answer

I just wanted to add that jwt.decode has a built-in method to check "exp"
and it does check it by default (https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/blob/96474ecfb6ad3ce16f41b0814ab5126d58725e2a/jose/jwt.py#L82)

so to make sure your token has been expired you can just handle the corresponding exception **ExpiredSignatureError**

```py
try:
    # decode token and extract username and expires data
    payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    username: str = payload.get("sub")
except ExpiredSignatureError: # <---- this one
    raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="token has been expired")
except JWTError:
    raise credentials_exception
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer since it is the right way to deal with the case.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to check if it is expired while validating the token at get_current_user(). I was facing same problem. because...
At first I set expiration time==60,
(ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 60)
that generated a token, with that token I was testing api.
than I set expiration time==1 and did not generated a token,
(ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 1)
expecting that after one minute the previous token will expire but that did not happen because the previous token had 60 minute life.

so, I created new token , tested api with that token. every thing was fine.
after one minute new token got expired.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above does not account that the token_data.expires needs to be converted to a utc date time object.

```
# check token expiration
if expires is None:
    raise credentials_exception
if datetime.utcnow() > datetime.utcfromtimestamp(token_data.expires):
    raise credentials_exception
return user
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the example code which doesnt propogate error as JWT does token signature checks and all you need todo is expose the error by propogating the error.

```
 def get_current_user_from_token(
        token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme), db: Session = Depends(get_db)
    ):
        credentials_exception = lambda x : HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=x,
        )
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[settings.ALGORITHM]
            )
            username: str = payload.get("sub")
            print("username/email extracted is ", username)
            if username is None:
                raise credentials_exception('Could not validate login or error in username/pass')
        except JWTError as e:
            raise credentials_exception(str(e))
        user = get_user(username=username, db=db)
        if user is None:
            raise credentials_exception('Could not validate login')
        return user
```